# How to get currently displayed fragment in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm new with viewPagers. Here is my problem. I've got a `viewPager` containing  3 fragments, inside an activity. I've a **Next** button which triggers different actions according to different fragments. Currently I'm applying following method:

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0){
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1), true);
        }else if(viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1){
            // trigger something
        }
    }
});
```

**When I am in position 0**, if I click next button, viewPager swipes to second fragment and **both conditions are triggered**! Isn't it supposed to be the first one only ? How to trigger one action at a time for corresponding fragment position? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if `viewPager.getCurrentItem()` is returning 0, only `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1), true);` will be executed, not the code in the place of `// trigger something`, there must be something else going on there

Comment: When viewpager goes to position 0 to position 1, it also executes position 1's actions. Weird isn't it?

Comment: could you please post more code?

Comment: You have a `viewPager` object and a `mViewPager` object? This doesn't look right for a start.. both `if else` conditions won't be triggered unless there is a double fire on the click listener, or something similar .. add logging..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
         if(viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0){
           viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1,true);
         }
         else if(viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1){
            // trigger something
         }
       }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Tried this but still getting same result. :(

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project and build it again? Try invalidate cash and restart too.

Answer (score 0):

**Perform operation in listener call back methods**

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        //Do it here
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: how is this related to the question?